# what is the probability of sample variance when true variance and true mean is unknown?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, variance, unbiased-estimator

Sample Variance by definition is $s^2 =\frac{1}{n-1} \sum{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$

When the population distribution is normal and true variance $\sigma^2$ is known, Sample Variance follows the chisq distribution via the following transformation: $(n-1)\frac{s^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$. From which we can calculate the probability of a sample variance at a point/within an interval **IF WE KNOW THE TRUE VARIANCE**. How do we find the probability of sample variance when the true variance and mean is unknown?

Comment: The distribution doesn't change depending on whether we know it or not. We must have object permanence here.

Comment: @user551504 good point, I changed question to ask for how to find the probabbility instead

Comment: You would need a proper prior distribution for the population variance to answer this

Comment: In a frequentist context, it seems best to 'pivot' the relationship $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1)$ to make a 95% confidence for $\sigma^2.$

Comment: With a continuous population distribution with $\sigma^2>0$, the *probability* of any specific sample variance is $0$.